# SnapSVG Tutorial

Tags: svg, svg-animate, snap.svg

I just starting Working with [SnapSvg](http://snapsvg.io) plugin, But it seems the plugin very little teaching resource,
Is there any `Ebook` or course about `SnapSVG`?

Comment: the *getting started* wizard and the *docs* are great. do you need anything else to get you started?

Comment: Yeah i check that,i see the `rephael` starting book: http://www.packtpub.com/raphael-javascript-starter/book ,i need something like that but for `Snapsvg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snap is quite new, so you won't see a lot of established resources. The one Mohammad links should be a good start. I've also been compiling some of the test Snap stuff I do [here](http://svg.dabbles.info/). It has quite a few examples that are relatively self explanatory.

Its also worth reading things on Raphael. Raphael was written by the same author, and is good for compatibility with older browsers. A lot of the examples and things like transform strings are basically the same, so in many cases you can do similar things. So if you read an ebook on Raphael, it will be quite helpful.

Comment: yeah that's quite new,i will checking your stuff,thanks for you help

Answer (score 1):

look these links maybe help you

http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/6537-getting-started-with-snapsvg.html

http://snapsvg.io/docs/

Comment: مرسی محمد رضا!
i see those article and resource before but i need more Resource and Richer!

Comment: your welcome,ok if i find more sure send to you